# Can't build using Stack on Windows

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am trying to build an almost empty Stack project but I get

```
Installing executable guessing2-exe in D:\learning\haskell\Glasgow\guessing2\.stack-work\install\2d25b1f1\bin
C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.10.4\mingw\bin\strip.exe: unable to rename 'D:\learning\haskell\Glasgow\guessing2\.stack-work\install\2d25b1f1\bin\guessing2-exe.exe'; reason: Invalid argument
'cabal copy' failed.  Error message:

--  While building package guessing2-0.1.0.0 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
  C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_3.2.1.0_ghc-8.10.4.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\274b403a copy
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I tried deleting the .stack-work folder but the problem persists. Could it be that the command line for the copy is too long for windows?

Edit: The folder has symlinks and that maybe causing the issue.

Comment: the path-limit is a good starting point - you should be able to deactivate it (if you have access to your Registry) - see for example here: https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/

Comment: seems your path is around 88characters though - so there should be plenty of *room*

Comment: can you try to build the project using a unix compability toolchain like `cygwin` or `msys2`? also: what `cabal` version are you using? AFAIK there has been an issue with some versions of cabal that the `copy` command did not work on windows and needed unix commands;

Comment: could be linked to this: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/5837